# Why does my model produce unrealistic output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, data-mining

I am trying to run a binary classification problem on people with diabetes and non-diabetes.

For labeling my datasets, I followed a simple rule. If a person has `T2DM` in his medical records, we label him as positive cases (`diabetes`) and if he doesn't have T2DM, we label him as `Non-T2DM`.

Since there are a lot of data points for each subject, meaning he has a lot of lab measurements, a lot of drugs taken, a lot of diagnoses recorded, etc, I ended up with 1370 features for each patient.

In my training, I have 2475 patients and in my testing, I have 2475 patients. (I already tried 70:30. Now am trying 50:50 still the same result (as 70:30))

My results are too good to be true as shown below

[image]

[image]

a) Should I reduce the number of features?

b) Is it overfitting?

c) Should I retain only the top features like top 20 features, top 10 features etc?

d) can help me understand why is this happening?

Comment: [Please don't just cross-post nearly-identical questions across multiple sites.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/84567/2853) Or at least link them together, so we don't duplicate work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are overfitting, and very much so.

Use a holdout sample to assess your model's predictive capabilities. Optimizing in-sample fits will usually lead to overfitting, especially with a large number of predictors, as in your case.

Consider using a regularized/penalized model to deal with your large number of predictors, like GLMNET or similar.

Finally, most of the KPIs your screenshot shows are misleading. [This thread is ostensibly about accuracy, but the very same criticisms also apply to sensitivity, specificity etc.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Comment: My understanding is that OP is evaluating on a test set, so I disagree with the diagnosis of overfitting: either there is data leakage, in which case the test set is invalid and we can't conclude anything, or the high performance is obtained on a valid test set, and this is not consistent with overfitting.